# access to vault since other server

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I have install a vault in my first server but a when access to my vault since other server

I create a config file `config.hcl` and i my file i put this

```
listener "tcp" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "myIP:8200"
}

# Advertise the non-loopback interface
api_addr = "https://myIP:8200"
cluster_addr = "https://myIp:8201"
```

like [hashicorp doc](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/listener/tcp.html)

but when i start the server like this `vault server -config=./config.hcl`

i have this error

```
Error initializing listener of type tcp: listen tcp4 myIp:8200: bind: address already in use
```

Comment: can you share your deployment yml? it looks like the vault server is already running

Comment: I am wondering why listener "tcp" configured twice ?